# Call controller function of admin from other controller of admin magento

Tags: magento

I have a controller function:

```
class Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function editInfoAction()
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

I want to call this function from other controller's (controller of adminhtml) function.
How can I achieve this? I have tried using:

```
$controllerInstance = Mage::getControllerInstance('Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController', $_REQUEST, new Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http());
$controllerInstance->editInfoAction();
```

But this is giving me error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController' not found in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\Mage.php</b> on line <b>520</b>
```

Please suggest me something and correct me if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$controllerInstance = Mage::getControllerInstance('Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController', $_REQUEST, new Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http());
$controllerInstance->editInfoAction()` why this type of u required

Comment: I am not able to get you, suggest me any other method if any. I can change to any other method to call the function.

Comment: why you have  create `Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController`extension

Comment: this is a plugin which I have downloaded, and now I want to call this plugin's function from my function.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by

```
// require you file        
if(!class_exists('Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController')) //in case the class already exists
{
    require_once('your class path');        
}

// instantiate your controller, using the `Mage:app()` object to grab the required request and response
$controller         = new Custom_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderinfoController(
                            Mage::app()->getRequest(),
                            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                        );        

// grab request and response object to manipulate as needed 
// (i.e. controller action expects post variables, etc.)

$request            = $controller->getRequest();
$response           = $controller->getResponse();

//manipulate things as per above

//call the action
$controller->editInfoAction();
```

Comment: sorry for replying late. It is not working , it is giving error :   <b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\community\OrderManager\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderinfoController.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\local\Indies\Partialpaymentadmin\controllers\Adminhtml\PartialpaymentadminController.php</b> on line <b>1013</b><br />

Comment: you are not providing proper path of the class. Fix that

Comment: I have tried using Mage::getBaseDir() and BS.DS constants. Both are giving error. Please tell me what is the correct way to include this?

Comment: This is the location where my class exists: C:\xampp\htdocs\ssl\app\code\community\OrderManager\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales‌​\OrderinfoController.php

Answer (score 0):

simple, the the autoloader is not seeing the controller, make sure that the plugins declaration is right and if it is simply is not finding the class, I'd say clear the config's cache